# PHP-CLI - how to reduce memory usage required for starting up PHP process

Tags: php, memory, command-line-interface

When PHP process starts up, it loads extensions, various configuration directives and creates global / env variables and such, which (I assume) uses up memory.

What I'm aiming to do is to bootstrap a simple PHP script that uses the least amount of memory possible for doing a specific task.

An example CLI script such as:

```
printf("\nHello World");
```

The code above does not rely on any $_ENV variables or certain PHP streams that are open by default, which, if they weren't present - would make PHP process use less memory.

What would you guys do to reduce memory usage to minimum, in order to run the code outlined above?

Answer (score 3):

For gaining a few bytes, you could run your PHP-Code in a clean environment:

```
env -i php -r 'var_dump(memory_get_peak_usage()); var_dump($GLOBALS);'
```

The `env -i` starts the script in a clean environment. You can see the difference by dumping the `$GLOBALS`. The function `memory_get_peak_usage()` shows the maximum consumed memory for the script. But on my system, I gain only a few KB with this method. It depends on your environment variables.

For a real optimization of the memory footprint, you have to look into your used extensions. To get your extension path, just execute a script like this:

```
php -r 'var_dump(ini_get("extension_dir"));'
```

You probably find some extensions like this:

```
curl.so
gd.so
json.so
[...]
```

These are the extensions you can load dynamically with dl(). They do not get into you memory usage. But if you like to see every extension loaded by the system, you can use the following command:

```
php -m
```

Comparing these lists, you will notice, there are much more extension available. These are compiled into PHP. To have a lower memory footprint, you would have to compile PHP from source.

To optimize PHP, you have to look into your code, which extensions you need. Getting the right options for ./configure is a time consuming task. For the beginning, see http://www.php.net/manual/de/configure.about.php

Usually, if you need a specific extension, you would go to the PHP-manual and take a look in the installation section for the extension, for zlib, this would be for example http://php.net/manual/de/zlib.installation.php

For your specific example you should try to compile PHP from source without options and test if it fulfills your needs.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but this isn't what I'm looking for. Even with no extensions loaded or compiled, running the script I've posted will chug up quite a bit of memory because of the bootstrapping process PHP goes through. What I'm wondering about are things such as using `get_defined_vars()` and unsetting them so internal symbol table is freed, get open streams and closing them and such.

Comment: I fear, that the thing you have in mind won't do any differences. Compared to the modules, the difference in memory usage should be marginally. If you like to take a look, use "php -r 'sleep(1000)'", use "ps" to get the PID and then use tools like "lsof" and "pmap".

Comment: That's what this question is here for, to find out what other people know about memory usage when bootstrapping the PHP process. I've measured the memory usage using valgrind already and detected extensions / code that uses memory the most. What I'd like to do is shave off everything to the last byte (I know it's not possible but we programmers always strive to do so). The example I provided with `get_defined_vars()` was just a hint of what I'd like to do. If you know anything else besides extension removal, let me know.

Comment: I've added a way to start a script in a clean environment, at least on my system.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `-n` "No php.ini file will be used", which prevents PHP's default extensions from loading.

You can then use `dl()` in your scripts, e.g. `dl('json.so')` to load any required extensions at runtime.

You'll also need to use `date_default_timezone_set()` to prevent a warning.